# Check null based on given parameters and use the not null values

Tags: c#, image

I have a method, and in the method I recieve:

- `img` = image file,
- `minwidth` = minimum width passing for filtering file
- `minHeight` = minimum height passing for filtering file
- `MaxWidth` = maximum width passing for filtering file
- `MinHeight` = maximum height passing for filtering file
- `type` = extension of image file (`jpg`, `png`, or `gif`. Only a single type gets passed in.)

`img` and `type` is **required** (not null) for the others, null is acceptable.

What I have to do is.

> Check the four parameter is null or not, and based on that, I have to check the condition with original image properties.

If I do with nested code, it will be bigger.
I want my code simplified.
Can someone try to make some smaller code?

Update:

Here is my code:

In that i checked only one minimum width only. Like that i have to check three properties.

```
if (img != null && type!=null)
            {
                if (minWidth != null)
                {
                    if (img.Width < minWidth)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (minHeight != null)
                        {
                            if (img.Height < minHeight)
                            {
                                return false;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (MaxWidth != null)
                                {
                                    if (img.Width > MaxWidth)
                                    {
                                        return false;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        if (Maxheight != null)
                                        {
                                            if (img.Height > Maxheight)
                                            {
                                                return false;
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {

                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }}
                }
```

Update:

I got simplified code

```
if (img != null && type != null)
            {
                string ImgFormat=null;
                if (img.RawFormat.Equals(System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg))
                {
                    ImgFormat = "jpg";
                }
                if (img.RawFormat.Equals(System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp))
                {
                    ImgFormat = "bmp";
                }
                if (img.RawFormat.Equals(System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif))
                {
                    ImgFormat = "gif";
                }
                if (img.RawFormat.Equals(System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png))
                {
                    ImgFormat = "png";
                }

                if (ImgFormat==type)
                {
                    String[] ImgPro = new String[4];
                    List<string> NotnullCount = new List<string>();
                    List<string> Executed = new List<string>();

                    if (minWidth == null)
                    {
                        minWidth = 0;
                        ImgPro[0] = minWidth.ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ImgPro[0] = minWidth.ToString();
                    }


                    if (minHeight == null)
                    {
                        minHeight = 0;
                        ImgPro[1] = minHeight.ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ImgPro[1] = minHeight.ToString();
                    }

                    if (MaxWidth == null)
                    {
                        MaxWidth = 0;
                        ImgPro[2] = MaxWidth.ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ImgPro[2] = MaxWidth.ToString();
                    }

                    if (Maxheight == null)
                    {
                        Maxheight = 0;
                        ImgPro[3] = Maxheight.ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ImgPro[3] = Maxheight.ToString();
                    }


                    for (int i = 0; i < ImgPro.Count(); i++)
                    {
                        if (ImgPro[i] != "0")
                        {
                            NotnullCount.Insert(NotnullCount.Count, ImgPro[i]);
                        }
                    }

                    if (ImgPro[0] != "0")
                    {
                        if (img.Width >= Convert.ToInt32(ImgPro[0]))
                        {
                            Executed.Insert(Executed.Count, ImgPro[0]);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    if (ImgPro[1] != "0")
                    {
                        if (img.Height >= Convert.ToInt32(ImgPro[1]))
                        {
                            Executed.Insert(Executed.Count, ImgPro[1]);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }

                    if (ImgPro[2] != "0")
                    {
                        if (img.Width <= Convert.ToInt32(ImgPro[2]))
                        {
                            Executed.Insert(Executed.Count, ImgPro[2]);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    if (ImgPro[3] != "0")
                    {

                        if (img.Height <= Convert.ToInt32(ImgPro[3]))
                        {
                            Executed.Insert(Executed.Count, ImgPro[3]);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }

                    if (NotnullCount.Count == Executed.Count)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
                return false;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Show the code you have and people may look into helping you refactoring it, may be better suited to code review though. But, please read [ask]

Comment: Code updated. Like that i have to write three times.

Comment: Where do they all come from? whats the method signature? what if they are null? basically, do all the null checks first then do the others separately, no need for nested ifs anywhere

Comment: This method is used to filter images based on image property and returns bool. In that four parameter which ever not null values, i will compare that parameter with actual image properties and if its okay with condition i will return true else false

Answer (score -1):

```
if((minWidth!=null && img.Width < minWidth)||(minHeight != null && img.Height < minHeight)||(MaxWidth != null && img.Width > MaxWidth)||(Maxheight != null && img.Height > Maxheight))
{
   return false; 
}
```

Perhaps something like this to get rid of the ,,nested code" ?

Comment: In that above condition if any one is false, i cant return, I have to check the remaining three.

Comment: Yeah but that's pretty much what your code already does. If anyone of this conditions is true then you return false. That's what your code did. I thought you just wanted to have the same thing but refactored.

Comment: I Updated the correct and simplified code in post itself.